# How would i change the values of a particular attribute inside of an XML string value in sitecore

Tags: sitecore-client, powershell

im trying to change the value of target to "" inside of an XML string value.

Heres what ive got so far:

```
New-UsingBlock (New-Object Sitecore.Data.BulkUpdateContext) {

# Get Home items
$root = Get-Item -Path "master:/sitecore/content/sitename/Content/Common/Footer"
# Get its descendents
$allItems = @( ($root.Axes.GetDescendants() | Initialize-Item))

# Get all including Home
$allItems = @($root) + @(($root.Axes.GetDescendants() | Initialize-Item))

$allItems | ForEach-Object {
# Get the items
$currentItem = $_

# Get item fields and create loop
$currentItem.Fields | ForEach-Object {
    
    #Check the field type
    if ($_.type -eq "Linklist") ## Here is where i would like to change the target value
    {
        
        [Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField]$linkField = $currentItem.Fields[$_.name]
        
        Write-Host "Processing link": $currentItem.Fields[$_.name]
        
        #Update target for Internal Links
        if ($linkField.Linktype -eq 'internal')
        {
            $currentItem.Editing.BeginEdit()
            $linkField.target = ""
            $currentItem.Editing.EndEdit()
        }
        
        Write-Host "Link Processed": $currentItem.Fields[$_.name]
       
    }

    if ($_.type -eq "General Link")
    {
        [Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField]$linkField = $currentItem.Fields[$_.name]
        # Update target for Internal Links
        if ($linkField.Linktype -eq 'internal')
        {
            $currentItem.Editing.BeginEdit()
            $linkField.target = ""
            $currentItem.Editing.EndEdit()
        }
    }
}
}  
}
```

We have a custom field type of "Linklist" which is basically just a set of normal link field XML values wrapped inside of links tags.

Example:

```
<links><link id="{3078F4A4-21C6-4086-B0BA-BCECBBA43A79}" querystring="" target="New 
Browser" text="testing 2" anchor="" url="" title="" class="" 
linktype="internal" /><link text="testing56" anchor="" linktype="internal" class="" 
title="" target="_blank" querystring="" id="{3078F4A4-21C6-4086-B0BA-BCECBBA43A79}" /> 
</links>
```

[image]

What i would like to do is when the script is checking if the field is a data type of **linklist**, i want to access this field and change all of the **target** values to an empty string ("")

Can anyone tell me the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of reading your XML, checking all the target values, and updating them to blank.

```
[xml]$linkList = '<links><link id="{3078F4A4-21C6-4086-B0BA-BCECBBA43A79}" querystring="" target="New Browser" text="testing 2" anchor="" url="" title="" class="" linktype="internal" ></link><link id="{3078F4A4-21C6-4086-B0BA-BCECBBA43A79}" querystring="" target="New Browser" text="testing 2" anchor="" url="" title="" class="" linktype="internal" ></link></links>'

$xmlData =  [xml]$linkList

foreach($ver in $linkList.SelectNodes("links/*"))
{
    $ver.SetAttribute("target", "")
    Write-Host "attribute updated"
}

Write-Host $linkList.OuterXml
```

This will give you this output.

```
<links><link id="{3078F4A4-21C6-4086-B0BA-BCECBBA43A79}" querystring="" target="" text="testing 2" anchor="" url="" title="" class="" linktype="internal"></link><link id="{3078F4A4-21C6-4086-B0BA-BCECBBA43A79}" querystring="" target="" text
="testing 2" anchor="" url="" title="" class="" linktype="internal"></link></links>
```

You can also read the XML value from your field like this.

```
[xml]$linkList=$item.Fields["field name"]
```

Using the item update, you can update your custom field value with the new one. I guess using this example you will be able to complete your code.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just place this inside `if ($_.type -eq "Linklist")` condition, it will modify only if *linktype* is *internal*

```
# Convert your linkList field raw value to xml
$xml=[XML]$currentItem.Fields[$_.name]
   
$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes("/links/link");

foreach($node in $nodes) {
    # check if linktype is internal
    if($node.GetAttribute("linktype") -eq 'internal')
    {
        $node.SetAttribute("target", "");
    }
}

    $currentItem.Editing.BeginEdit()
    $currentItem.Fields[$_.name] = $xml.outerxml
    $currentItem.Editing.EndEdit()

Write-Host "Link Processed": $currentItem.Fields[$_.name]
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: hi ive tested this piece of code however im getting the following error: ForEach-Object : Unable to index into an object of type Sitecore.Collections.FieldCollection.
At line:16 char:27
+     $currentItem.Fields | ForEach-Object {

Comment: Was it working before ? Or it started breaking after you added above code ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are on the right track, but you need to make a small adjustment to your code to handle the XML content within the "Linklist" field. You can use the [Sitecore.Data.Fields.XmlField] class to work with the XML content of the field.

Try to use below script:

```
 New-UsingBlock (New-Object Sitecore.Data.BulkUpdateContext) {

    # Get Home items
    $root = Get-Item -Path "master:/sitecore/content/sitename/Content/Common/Footer"
    # Get its descendents
    $allItems = @( ($root.Axes.GetDescendants() | Initialize-Item))

    # Get all including Home
    $allItems = @($root) + @(($root.Axes.GetDescendants() | Initialize-Item))

    $allItems | ForEach-Object {
        # Get the items
        $currentItem = $_

        # Get item fields and create loop
        $currentItem.Fields | ForEach-Object {

            # Check the field type
            if ($_.type -eq "Linklist") {
                [Sitecore.Data.Fields.XmlField]$xmlField = $currentItem.Fields[$_.name]

                Write-Host "Processing link": $currentItem.Fields[$_.name]

                # Update target for Internal Links
                $xmlContent = $xmlField.InnerXml
                $xmlDoc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
                $xmlDoc.LoadXml($xmlContent)

                foreach ($linkNode in $xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//link[@linktype='internal']")) {
                    $linkNode.SetAttribute("target", "")
                }

                $xmlField.InnerXml = $xmlDoc.OuterXml

                $currentItem.Editing.BeginEdit()
                $currentItem.Editing.EndEdit()

                Write-Host "Link Processed": $currentItem.Fields[$_.name]
            }

            if ($_.type -eq "General Link") {
                [Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField]$linkField = $currentItem.Fields[$_.name]
                # Update target for Internal Links
                if ($linkField.Linktype -eq 'internal') {
                    $currentItem.Editing.BeginEdit()
                    $linkField.target = ""
                    $currentItem.Editing.EndEdit()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```